# VS2010 Local Resource Suffix Issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Resource file generated from Tools--> Generate Local Resources creates respective keys having the suffix "Resource1".

Is there a way to get rid of the suffix "Resource1" and make it use the exact control name for the resource key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's described in this [issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/121450/generate-local-resource-and-resource1). The Resource suffix is to help prevent name clashes between controls. Without it, it would break in some circumstances.

Is it purely the code generation you want to customize? You could always use a [`Custom Resource Manager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx) to remap the resource keys to your own convention (without suffix). It does mean creating your own implementation to pull out the resources created from `RESX`, but I've done it this in the past with some help (copy/paste) from reflector.

It would allow you to use shortcuts (no suffix) in your syntax when referring to resources, but it wouldn't affect the code gen side of things. A find and replace fixes that, or a custom tool.

Comment: I would argue that instead of putting {ControlName}Resource{index}, MS could have used this format {ControlName}, or {ControlName}{index} if the control does not support the property ID.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because the resource key names cannot be parametrized. If anybody comes with a better solution for this problem, I would not mind accepting that as the answer instead. Thank you TheCodeKing, all the bounty is yours. :)

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was a pretty workable solution, although I agree it should be better named by default.